# Why does my app (which uses Google Maps API 2) crash every time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, classnotfoundexception, google-maps-api-2

Could you please look at my code and tell me why my application crashes every time?

**Main.java**

```
package com.lakshya.maps2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

I created the key using the SHA-1 fingerprint displaying in Eclipse > Windows > Preferences > Android > Build or something like that.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.lakshya.maps2"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="8"
           android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission
        android:name="com.lakshya.maps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.lakshya.maps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission           android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDUWhpYNe9M2w8"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.lakshya.maps2.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

---

**Logcat errors**

```
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lakshya.maps2/com.lakshya.maps2.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at com.lakshya.maps2.Main.onCreate(Main.java:14)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    ... 11 more
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.lakshya.maps2-1.apk]
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-04 10:55:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(20176):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: what does your stacktrace say??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
<uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

So you need to extend `FragmentActivity` and use `SupportMapFragment`.

```
public class Main extends Activity{
```

Should be

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{
```

This

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

should be

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

You should have the meta tag as a child of application tag

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please remove below line from fragment tag and clean and build the project

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: what has this gotta do with the crash??

Comment: because there are two xmlns tags in xml file but only one is enough

Comment: that is no the reason for the crash